# POST AJAX request via HTTPHandler to another HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest, httphandler

I have a button on a website which sends an AJAX request to a .NET HTTPHandler. In the ProcessRequest method of this handler, it then took the query string parameters, and created a new WebRequest to another URL and appended the parameters onto it.

However, the AJAX request has been changed to use POST rather than GET (amongst other things).
This is what I need to do:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // Take POST data from request and create a new request
    // with it to another URL
}
```

What makes it more complicated is that the POST data contains multiple arrays all called 'points' which hold latitude, longitude and altitude. So I can't use context.Request["points"] as that doesn't return an array of my points arrays. And I've tried using context.Request.Form.GetValues("points") but that doesn't seem to work, presumably because the data wasn't submitted as a form.

**Edit:**

AJAX request is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: self.stationsAllFile,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            // store stations as kml string
            self.stationsCurrent = response;
            self.showStations(self.stationsCurrent, false);
            self.listStations(self.stationsCurrent, finishedLoading);
            var stations = $.parseXML(response),
                $stations = $(stations),
                $placemarks = $stations.find('Placemark');
            $placemarks.each(function () {
                var $placemark = $(this),
                    latLng = $placemark.find('coordinates').text(),
                    latLngSplit = latLng.split(','),
                    lng = latLngSplit[0],
                    lat = latLngSplit[1];
                excludePoints.push(lng + ',' + lat + ',0.000000');
            });
            // do we need to go again?
            if(endPoint < route.length) {
                self.processRoute(route, endPoint + 1, excludePoints);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            self.showError(self.language.errors.unknownError);
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
```

Example POST data (pasted from Fiddler):

points%5B%5D=-2.2349300000000003%2C53.48073%2C0.000000&points%5B%5D=-2.26805%2C53.559020000000004%2C0.000000&type=route

Comment: could you post a sample of your post data and the code snippet of how you are preparing ajax call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get POST data as array with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824601/how-to-get-post-data-as-array-with-c-sharp)